# How to mask SSN in a string using regex

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, regex

How to  mask SSN  in a string ?

I am  have the following scenario

```
string str1 = "asdasfasdfasdf sfhagfdad SSN:123456789";
```

my required output `"asdasfasdfasdf sfhagfdad SSN:*********"`

I tried the below code

```
Regex ssnRegex = new Regex("(?:\bSSN:\b)(?:[0-9]{3})(?:[0-9]{2})(?:[0-9]{4})");
string formattedSSN = ssnRegex.Replace(t1, "SSN:-XXX-XX-XXXX");
```

I  think i am missing to capture "SSN:"  Could you please tell me how to get the above output

Comment: it will be wiser to use string.replace here as you know where your input starts and where it ends. find SSN: in the string and replace the rest of the characters with *.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `String.Replace`?

```
string str1 = "asdasfasdfasdf sfhagfdad SSN:123456789";

//Get starting position
int position = str1.IndexOf("SSN:") + 4;

//Extract social
string ssn = str1.Substring(position, 9);

//Update string
str1 = str1.Replace(ssn, "XXX-XX-XXXX");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Replace("asdasfasdfasdf sfhagfdad SSN:123456789", @"\d{3}[-]?\d{2}[-]?\d{4}", "***")
output: "asdasfasdfasdf sfhagfdad SSN:***"


Regex.Replace("asdasfasdfasdf sfhagfdad SSN:123456789", @"^*SSN:\d{3}[-]?\d{2}[-]?\d{4}", "SSN:***")
output: "asdasfasdfasdf sfhagfdad SSN:***"
```

Comment: I want to do same thing but leave the last 3 digits of the SSN string